How to return ng-select in typescript?
I am trying to add ng-select & ng-option in typescript (angular). But I am not sure if that is possible since ng-select is a component which is not rendered. How can I make this work?
@Component({
  selector: 'app-testing',
  templateUrl: './app-testing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-testing.component.scss']
})

export class TestCompontnt implements OnInit  {

ngOnInit() {}

example(type: string) {
    return `
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-checkable middle-align-table">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th style="width: 40%">TT</th>
                  <th>TT2</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <td>okej</td>
              <td>
                  <div class="input-group">
                      <input type="number" class="form-control">
                      <div class="input-group-append">
                          <ng-select>
                              <ng-option value="TEST">TEST</ng-option>
                          </ng-select>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </td>
          </tbody>
      </table>
    `;
  }
}

I tried to add dropdown menu to dynamic component.

You can not render Angular components via innerHTML. You should put your template into the app-testing.component.html file instead.

If you want to apply your template via innerHTML, you cannot use Angular components such as <ng-select>. Instead you need to use the native select and option elements from HTML.
<select>
  <option value="TEST">TEST</option>
</select>

If you want to use Angular components, you need to add the template to the <component-name>.component.html file, and not as string in your TypeScript code. See https://angular.dev/essentials/rendering-dynamic-templates
If you want to programmatically render an Angular component, please see https://angular.dev/guide/components/programmatic-rendering

Yes. But how do I make ng-select & ng-option work? I have already installed NgSelectModule.

@rammstein updated my answer.

Yeah I see. Thanks. But this is not the answer I am looking for. I believe I need to resolve this somehow with ViewContainerRef & TemplateRef.

@rammstein probably, I added another link to the answer which might be useful for you. However with the limited information available, I cannot give you a better answer.

You can use ng-template then pass the context as this and then finally render using ng-container
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NgSelectModule, FormsModule, CommonModule],
  template: `
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="select; context: {that: this}"></ng-container>
    <ng-template #select let-that="that">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-checkable middle-align-table">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th style="width: 40%">TT</th>
                      <th>TT2</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  <td>okej</td>
                  <td>
                      <div class="input-group">
                          <input type="number" class="form-control">
                          <div class="input-group-append">
                              <ng-select [(ngModel)]="that.selected">
                                  <ng-option value="TEST">TEST</ng-option>
                              </ng-select>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </td>
              </tbody>
          </table>
    </ng-template>
      {{selected}}

  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  selected = '';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
